# How to find $ \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x-\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{4x+1} -3} $ without derivatives and l'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to find 
$$
\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x-\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{4x+1} -3}
$$
but without using derivatives, and l'Hopital.

I tried to rationalize and it didn't work.
Could anyone help please?

Comment: Show us what you obtained after the rationalization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{x-\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{4x+1}-3}\times\dfrac{\sqrt{4x+1}+3}{\sqrt{4x+1}+3}\times\dfrac{x+\sqrt{x+2}}{x+\sqrt{x+2}} = \lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{(x+1)(x-2)}{4(x-2)}\times\dfrac{\sqrt{4x+1}+3}{x+\sqrt{x+2}}$$